# HTML/CSS Underline full width

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I'm trying to figure out how to make the underlines/borders full width for each line without adding 
 in the paragraphs. Does anyone have any ideas how I should approach this?

The two solutions I have so far is to add the  or create an image of it, but that is not the ideal case.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**HTML**

```
<p>We are always on the lookout for great talent. Please send in your resume or portfolio to test@test.com. The following positions are open.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    border-top: thin soild #000;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code or explain better your situation, I cant understand what your asking.

Comment: I'm trying to just mimic the image with underline/border.

Comment: Could it be the div or the item that it is in?

Comment: Right now I'm trying to not make each line it's seperate div for the sake of responsive and cleanliness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the line height is fixed you could do it with a gradient:

```
p{
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, transparent 19px, #333 20px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2VG4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t2VG4/

Can you look at that and help me fix the gradient issue under each line?

Comment: They are not solid black lines. I need all of the lines to be solid.

Comment: You mean match the width of the font, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/t2VG4/2/)? Just play with the color-stops until you get the right size and position

Answer (score 1):

I had a minor issue where the lines appeared as gradients, the fix was to specify that the switch from transparent to black took place over 0.1px so that its undetectable

```
p {line-height: 27px;
    color: #333;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg
, transparent, transparent 24px, #333 24.1px, #333 25.1px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put text into span element.

http://jsfiddle.net/nukec/3bUFC/

```
<span style="border-bottom: 1px solid red">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </span>
```

Comment: That is close, but I want to make sure that each line reaches the full width. Please look at the image.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS solution would be to set the `line-height` (30px here) and then adjust the stop locations on the `repeating-linear-gradient` to align with the text (29px and 30px):

```
p {
    line-height:30px;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, transparent 29px, grey 30px);
    border-top:1px solid grey;
}
```

However, keep in mind that each browser engine's gradient generator was built towards smooth color transitions, not pixel-crisp edges, so your results may vary. The best solution would probably be to create a tiling image (with transparency and a horizontal line) and use that as the `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutly not, must be a totally blank underline full page width.

TBNK